# How to read and write the records in EhCache?

Tags: java, ehcache

Hi All,
        My current requirement is to store and read the records using EhCache. I am new to EhCache Implementation. I have read the EhCache Documentation and started to implement. I have done the records insert part and also read part. While the records are inserted, there will be *.data nd *.index files are created. Following is Code.

```
public class Driver
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    CacheManager cm = CacheManager.create("ehcache.xml");
    Cache cache = cm.getCache("test");
    // I do a couple of puts
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        cache.put(new Element("key1", "val1"));
            cache.flush();
    }
    System.out.println(cache.getKeys());
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        Element el = cache.get("key"+i);
        System.out.println(el.getObjectValue());
    }
    cm.shutdown();  
    }
    }
```

Now what the issue is **cm.shutdown()**. If I am commenting this line and comment out the insert part and run the program means, Not able to retrieve the records and also *.index file is deleted. So In real scenario if the program is stopped abruptly means we can't read the records after startup. I want to know why the file is deleted and why I cant read the records in this situation... The Exception coming in the console is

```
net.sf.ehcache.util.SetAsList@b66cc
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at Driver.main(Driver.java:29)...
```

Any Input is needed Please..

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is correct and the expected behaviour is correct too. Caches are typically used to enhance application performance by providing frequently used data quickly, while avoiding costly trips to datastore.

Not all applications need to persist cache after the system is shutdown- and that's the default behaviour you are seeing (Most applications will build cache on application startup or as requests start coming in). The data you are caching is in heap - and as soon as your JVM dies- the cache is gone. Now you want to persist it beyond restart? There are options available. Loook up [here](http://ehcache.org/documentation/get-started/storage-options)

And I am copying the code snippet right from the same page:

```
DiskStoreConfiguration diskStoreConfiguration = new DiskStoreConfiguration();
diskStoreConfiguration.setPath("/my/path/dir");
// Already created a configuration object ...
configuration.addDiskStore(diskStoreConfiguration);
// By adding configuration for storing the cache in a file - you are not using default cache manager
CacheManager mgr = new CacheManager(configuration);
```

In addition, you will have to also configure the persistence options as explained [here](http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration/fast-restart)

Again copying code snippet from link:

```
<cache>
   <persistence strategy=”localRestartable” synchronousWrites=”true”/>
</cache>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Vishal, Thanks For your answer. I have set the DiskStoreConfiguration in ehCache.xml file itself as <diskStore path="D:/techinal session/EhcachePOC" />.... But still I am not able to get it... Could you please guide me is there anything wrong?

Comment: But are you passing configuration object to CM?

Comment: Oh and what is your eviction and expiry policy?

Comment: I have created the CacheManager by using the ehcache.xml.. 
CacheManager cm = CacheManager.create("ehcache.xml");
So in that XML itself diskstoreConfiguration is added. So the cacheManger will have the configuration object... no need to add it via programmatically.. Am I right?

Comment: I am new to this EhCache... So could you please explain in detail.. What about Eviction and Expiry policy?

Comment: Check http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration/fast-restart , you will have to also configure <cache><persistence strategy=”localRestartable” synchronousWrites=”true”/></cache> , as the default strategy is none. I updated original answer

Comment: Hi Vishal, I have added this in Cache Configuration... But the Follwoing Exception Occured while running the program...

Exception in thread "main" net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Error configuring from ehcache.xml. Initial cause was Error configuring from input stream. Initial cause was null:13: Element <cache> does not allow nested <persistence> elements.
 at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:78)
 at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(CacheManager.java:769)
 at Driver.main(Driver.java:16)
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Error

Comment: Anand I have given inputs to best of my knowledge. Looks like there is a syntax error in your ehcache.xml - please check documentation and correct

Comment: Chat is blocked - can only comment